# Efficient way to update a column from a table using LinqSql?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

In Sql, for example I would do:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColum='value' WHERE Id=132
```

How would be the equivalent in a EF Code First database?

### UPDATE:

Seeing the responses, I need to clarify my question. I am looking for an efficient way to update one column. If I use Single() or any similar function, the performance is very poor for two reasons: 1) There are 2 SQL statements, one for SELECT, and one for UPDATE, 2) The Single function retrieves all columns.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColum='value' WHERE Id=132
```

The above sentence is efficient because it is only one transaction and no values are sent to the client from the server. I would like which would be the equivalent sentence in Linq Sql.

Answer (score 1):

SingleOrDefault would return the object if exists in the db, or null otherwise:

```
var row = context.MyTable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 132);
if(row != null) {
  row.MyColumn = "Value";
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that this only works when Id is unique and exists, it will crash of there is not exactly one row.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with one transaction.you need first to check that row you want to update is in your table or not

```
using (MyEntities me=new MyEntities())
{
     if( (from t in me.MyTables where mt.Id == 132 select t).Any())
     {    
         MyTable mt= (from t in me.MyTables where mt.Id == 132 select t).Single();
         mt.MyColumn= "Value";
         me.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```